# Overlays caused by camera movement in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, scenekit

I have the following code in my SceneKit app to move the camera after a collision:

```
let presNode = contact.nodeA.presentationNode()

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(1.0)

SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock() {
    println("Moved camera")
}

_cameraNode.position.x = presNode.position.x
_cameraNode.position.y = 0
_cameraNode.position.z = presNode.position.z + 120
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

However, I'm having an issue in which moving the camera sometimes causes the frame before the animation to appear as an overlay in the final frame, like this:
[image]

Instead,it should look like this:
[image: correct rendering]

However, this doesn't happen every time, and there's no clear (to me) reason why it happens some times and not others. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: have you enabled jittering on the view?

Comment: That might be it, thanks! I turned jittering off and it seems to have fixed the issue, although now the camera isn't animating its movement at all in some cases.